# How to drag and drop an UIWebView around

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, drag-and-drop

I have a simple iOS app (running on iPad) that has only an `UIWebView` filling the full screen.

Now I added a new `UIWebView`(a lot smaller that the previous one) and let it sit on top of the first one.

Is there a way for me to be able to drag and drop the second `UIWebView` around on the first one?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to add drag capabilities to any view.  Using it, you will be given the coordinates of the drag (you can set the view's frame with this), and are given a flag when pan has stopped (your drop).

Here's an example taken from the web: [Working with UIGestureRecognizers](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/)